# Parent Class don't catch exceptions from overwritten method in child class

Tags: php, oop, exception, inheritance, slim

I have this problem with [Slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/). I have class Template that have render method and I want for Slim to render objects of this class if they are returned by route handlers

```php
$app->get('/test', function() {
    return new Template('main', function() use ($error) {
        return array(
            'content' => "Hello"
        );
    });
});
```

it work I created child class (in System.php)

```php
class System extends Slim {
   function __constructor() {
       Slim::__construct();
   }
   private function auto_render_fun($callable) {
        $app = $this;
        return function() use ($callable, $app) {
            $args = func_get_args();
            $ret = call_user_func_array($callable, $args);
            if ($ret instanceof Template) {
                //render Template - Slim ignore return value
                $app->response()->body($ret->render());
            }
        };
    }
    protected function mapRoute($args) {
        $last = count($args)-1;
        $args[$last] = $this->auto_render_fun($args[$last]);
        return Slim::mapRoute($args);
    }
}
```

I wanted to do the same thing with notFound

```php
$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    $response = $app->response();
    $response['Content-Type'] = 'text/html';
    return new Template('main', function() {
        return array('content' => new Template('error_404', null));
    });
});
```

so I've overwritten notFound function to wrap Closure and render it's return value

First I try to use smaller code

```php
public function notFound($callable = null) {
    if (!is_null(($callable))) {
        $this->router->notFound($this->auto_render_fun($callable));
    } else {
        Slim::notFound();
    }
}
```

I also try this (copy and modify old code).

```php
public function notFound($callable = null) {
    if ( !is_null($callable) ) {
        $this->router->notFound($this->auto_render_fun($callable));
        //            $this->router->notFound($callable);    // old line
    } else {
        ob_start();
        $customNotFoundHandler = $this->router->notFound();
        if ( is_callable($customNotFoundHandler) ) {
            call_user_func($customNotFoundHandler);
        } else {
            call_user_func(array($this, 'defaultNotFound'));
        }
        $this->halt(404, ob_get_clean());
    }
}
```

but the reason why it didn't work is that it trow `Slim_Exception_Stop` that's suppose to be cached by Slim here is that line for code that call `$this->notFound();` 
https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Slim.php#L1160
it's inside try..catch.

Here is stack trace (I cached it inside notFound function - but it should be handled in Slim class).

```
Slim_Exception_Stop in file libs/Slim/Slim/Slim.php at 862
0: Slim->stop() in libs/Slim/Slim/Slim.php at 882
1: Slim->halt(integer, string) in libs/System.php at 187
2: System->notFound() in libs/Slim/Slim/Slim.php at 1161
3: Slim->call() in libs/Slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php at 84
4: Slim_Middleware_Flash->call() in libs/Slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php at 91
5: Slim_Middleware_MethodOverride->call() in libs/Slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php at 65
6: Slim_Middleware_PrettyExceptions->call() in libs/Slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php at 65
7: Slim_Middleware_PrettyExceptions->call() in libs/Slim/Slim/Slim.php at 1098
8: Slim->run() in index.php at 573
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason, exception was handled as it should but there was not content. I wrongly assume that it's something with Classes, but simply the Slim code have bugs.

```php
public function halt( $status, $message = '' ) {
    $this->cleanBuffer();
    $this->response->status($status);
    $this->response->body($message);
    $this->stop();
}
```

function overwrite data that you use in the handler like this

```php
$app->notFound(function() {
   $app->response()->body('Error');
});
```

won't work, function not found should look like this

```php
public function notFound($callable = null) {
    if (!is_null(($callable))) {
        $this->router->notFound($this->auto_render_fun($callable));
    } else {
        $customNotFoundHandler = $this->router->notFound();
        if (is_callable($customNotFoundHandler)) {
            call_user_func($customNotFoundHandler);
        } else {
            call_user_func(array($this, 'defaultNotFound'));
        }
        $this->response->status(404);
        $this->stop();
    }
}
```